# How can I select an option from dropdown with selenium?

Tags: python, wordpress, selenium-webdriver, tablepress

I'm trying to automate the process to replace existing table in TablePress Wordpress plugin with Python and Selenium webdriver, but I stuck at the point where I should choose the existing table from a dropdown. How can I select the "ID bcwd_stock_auto: (no name)" option of this dropdown?

```
<td class="column-2">
    <div class="jdropdown jdropdown-default">
        <div class="jdropdown-container-header">
        <input class="jdropdown-header jss_object" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="— Select or type —"></div>
        <div class="jdropdown-container" style="min-width: 744.031px;"><div class="jdropdown-close">Done</div>
        <div class="jdropdown-content">
        <div class="jdropdown-item">
            <div class="jdropdown-description">— Select or type —</div></div>
            <div class="jdropdown-item">
            <div class="jdropdown-description">ID bcwd_current_stock: (no name)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="jdropdown-item">
            <div class="jdropdown-description">ID bcwd_stock_auto: (no name)</div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="jdropdown-backdrop"></div>
        </div>
<select id="tables-import-existing-table" name="import[existing_table]" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">— Select or type —</option>
    <option value="bcwd_current_stock">ID bcwd_current_stock: (no name)</option>
    <option value="bcwd_stock_auto">ID bcwd_stock_auto: (no name)</option>
</select>
</td>
```

I tried:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('tables-import-existing-table'))
select.select_by_value('bcwd_stock_auto')
```

And this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select//option[contains(., 'bcwd_stock_auto')]"))).click()
```

But with no luck. Any idea how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked:

```
dropd = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.jdropdown-container-header input.jdropdown-header.jss_object')
dropd.click()
dropd.send_keys(Keys.DOWN, Keys.DOWN, Keys.DOWN, Keys.RETURN)
```